# Fast parsing of string that allows escaped characters?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parser-combinators, attoparsec

I'm trying to parse a string that can contain escaped characters, here's an example:

```
import qualified Data.Text as T

exampleParser :: Parser T.Text
exampleParser = T.pack <$> many (char '\\' *> escaped <|> anyChar)
  where escaped = satisfy (\c -> c `elem` ['\\', '"', '[', ']'])
```

The parser above creates a `String` and then packs it into `Text`. Is there any way to parse a string with escapes like the above using the functions for efficient string handling that attoparsec provides? Like `string`, `scan`, `runScanner`, `takeWhile`, `...`

Parsing something like `"one \"two\" \[three\]"` would produce `one "two" [three]`.

**Update**:

Thanks to @epsilonhalbe I was able to come out with a generalized solution perfect for my needs; note that the following function doesn't look for matching escaped characters like `[..]`, `".."`, `(..)`, etc; and also, if it finds an escaped character that is not valid it treats `\` as a literal character.

```
takeEscapedWhile :: (Char -> Bool) -> (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Text
takeEscapedWhile isEscapable while = do
  x <- normal
  xs <- many escaped
  return $ T.concat (x:xs)
  where normal = Atto.takeWhile (\c -> c /= '\\' && while c)
        escaped = do
          x <- (char '\\' *> satisfy isEscapable) <|> char '\\'
          xs <- normal
          return $ T.cons x xs
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible writing some escaping code, `attoparsec` and `text` - altogether it is pretty straightforward - seeing you have already worked with parsers

```
import Data.Attoparsec.Text as AT
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Text (Text)

escaped, quoted, brackted :: Parser Text
normal =  AT.takeWhile (/= '\\')
escaped = do r <- normal
             rs <- many escaped'
             return $ T.concat $ r:rs
  where escaped' = do r1 <- normal
                      r2 <- quoted <|> brackted
                      return $ r1 <> r2

quoted = do string "\\\""
            res <- normal
            string "\\\""
            return $ "\""<>res <>"\""

brackted = do string "\\["
              res <- normal
              string "\\]"
              return $ "["<>res<>"]"
```

then you can use it to parse the following test cases

```
Prelude >: MyModule
Prelude MyModule> import Data.Attoparsec.Text as AT
Prelude MyModule AT> import Data.Text.IO as TIO
Prelude MyModule AT TIO>:set -XOverloadedStrings
Prelude MyModule AT TIO> TIO.putStrLn $ parseOnly escaped "test"
test
Prelude MyModule AT TIO> TIO.putStrLn $ parseOnly escaped "\\\"test\\\""
"test"
Prelude MyModule AT TIO> TIO.putStrLn $ parseOnly escaped "\\[test\\]"
[test]
Prelude MyModule AT TIO> TIO.putStrLn $ parseOnly escaped "test \\\"test\\\" \\[test\\]"
test "test" [test]
```

note you have to escape the escapes - that's why you see `\\\"` instead of `\"`

Also if you just parse it will print the `Text` values escaped, like

```
Right "test \"text\" [test]"
```

for the last example.

If you parse a file you write simpley escaped text in the file.

`test.txt`

```
I \[like\] \"Haskell\"
```

then you can

```
Prelude MyModule AT TIO> file <- TIO.readFile "test.txt" 
Prelude MyModule AT TIO> TIO.putStrLn $ parseOnly escaped file
I [like] "Haskell"
```

Comment: The code required makes you think if the trade of performance over simplicity is worth it